# Lossless, dependency preserving decomposition of a relation in 3rd Normal Form

Tags: database, database-normalization, bcnf

I am learning about normalization of databases and I came across the following problem:

```
 Given the following relation, BOSQID and its functional dependencies
 F={S->D, I->B, IS->Q, B->O},
```

How would I go about finding a lossless, dependency preserving decomposition of the above into 3rd normal form?

Not really sure what 3rd normal form is, I looked it up and found the following requirements:

```
1. The relation R (table) is in second normal form (2NF)

2. Every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent on every superkey of R.
```

After reading the above, I'm not too sure on where to begin. Also, not sure if it is helpful or relevant to answering the question, but I found the candidate key to be

```
IS
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

We have a relation, R(BOSQID) and its functional dependencies:

F={S→D, I→B, IS→Q, B→O}

As, you have concluded that only {SI} is candidate key, since {SI}+ = SIDBQO=BOSQID and no subset of {SI} is computed all attributes of relation R.

According to definition of partial dependency {S→D, I→B} are partial dependencies, since subset of candidate keys map non-prime attribute(s).

According to 2NF, partial dependencies (i.e., {S→D, I→B}) not allowed. But {IS→Q, B→O} both are allowed in 2NF. Finally, relation R is not in 2NF.

To achieve 2NF, we decompose the relation R such that decomposition should satisfy lossless join and dependency preserving relations.

I decompose it in relations R1(ISQ) with F1={IS→Q}, R2(SD) with F2={S→D}, and R3(IBO) with F3={I→B, B→O}.

Now, candidate key(s) and normal form of relations R1, R2, and R3, are {IS} with BCNF, {S} with BCNF, and {I} with 2 NF respectively.

Since, decomposition R3 is not in 3NF, since FD {B→O}, neither B is Candidate of R3 nor O is prime attribute of R3. So, we need to decompose again to achieve 3NF in relation R3 such that decomposition should satisfy lossless join and dependency preserving relations.

I decompose R3 in R31(IB) with F31={I→B}, and R32(BO) with F32={B→O}. Now candidate key(s) and normal form of relation R31 and R32 are, {I} with BCNF and {B} with BCNF respectively.

> Therefore, final BCNF as well as 3NF decomposition is R1(ISQ), R2(SD), R31(IB) and R32(BO).

Comment: Nice explanation but R2(ISD) should be just R2(SD) if i'm not mistaken.

Comment: @captainmonk, yes you are correct. It is better to remove redundancy.